# Did anything change to ngFormControl in @angular/forms 0.3.0?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm upgrading my Angular app from rc4 to rc5, including an update of the angular forms from 0.2.0 to 0.3.0.
Since then I've been getting the following error, which seems to relate to a change to ngFormControl in forms 0.3.0

```
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFormControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("nput type="text" class="form-control search-input" name="search" placeholder="Search..." [value]="" [ERROR ->][ngFormControl]="searchFormControl">
```

The line referred to codes a search box in one of my component templates:

```
<p [hidden]=hideSearch>
  <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" name="search" placeholder="Search..." [value]="" [ngFormControl]="searchFormControl">
</p>
```

I've been unable to find any info that this functionality got changed. What's the proper alternative to ngFormControl now then?

Edit: For context, here is the entire component header.component.ts (FormModule and ReactiveFormModule are loaded in app.module.ts)

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import { Control } from '@angular/common';
import { OrbitService } from './orbit.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

@Component({
  selector: 'orbit-header',

  template: `
    <div class="top-nav row">
      <h3 class="pull-left">Northmark</h3>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset10 pull-right">
        <p [hidden]=hideSearch>
        <!-- ng-model = [ngFormController] -->
          <input type="search" class="form-control search-input" name="search" placeholder="Search..." [value]="" [NgFormControl]="searchFormControl">
        </p>
        <p>
          <a class="log-out" (click)="orbitService.deleteCookie('ORBIT_COOKIE')">Log Out</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  `
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() private hideSearch: boolean;

  constructor(
    private orbitService: OrbitService) {
    this.searchFormControl = new Control();
  }

  @Output() onSubmit = new EventEmitter<string>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchFormControl.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(500)
      .subscribe(query => this.submit(query));
  }

  submit(query: string) {
    this.onSubmit.emit(query);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you import the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`? Please show more code.

Comment: FormsModule yes, ReactiveFormsModule no. What is  ReactiveFormsModule used for?

Comment: For model-driven forms. `FormsModule` is for template-driven forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[ngFormControl]="searchFormControl"
```

should be

```
[formControl]="searchFormControl"
```

and I think you need to import `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: Yup, that seems to do it!